# T.test in R...getting multiple p values

Tags: r, p-value

I'm trying to do a T.test between two data sets..

This is 'Dataset1'

```
TIME        5    10      15      20      25
Specimen no.                        
1          15.2 30.5     41     12.5         16.2
2          13.1 16.2    12.5    Na       13.2
3          16.11 45.7   11.4    18.9    11.7
4          11.2  Na    9.11    20.7      19
```

And another 'Dataset2'

```
TIME        5   10        15      20    25

Specimen no.                        
1       11.8    34.8    14.2    19.9    23.4
2         NA    6.4     29.2    32.7    17.1
3       10.0    35.5    38.5    28.3    27.3
4       18.7    NA      11.5    14.6    18.9
```

I just want to compare each 5 second interval from dataset1 to dataset2 using a t.test.  How do I get that list of p values

So far I only have this

```
t.test(dataset1[[2]],dataset2[[2]])$p.value...
```

Clearly this is wrong....coz I don't know how I can access certain columns from dataset1 and dataset2 ...I also have NA values that could get me error messages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the column numbers of `dataset1` and `dataset2` are equal, you can write a `for` loop as this:

```
pval = rep(0, ncol(dataset1))
for(i in 1:ncol(dataset1)){
    pval[i] = t.test(dataset1[, i], dataset2[, i], na.action = na.omit)$p.value
}
```

Here, `dataset1[, i]` means the `i`th column and `na.omit` will remove the `NA`s and then perform the test.

Comment: Hi cogitovita, thanks for the answer, but for some reason I'm getting this error message:  Error in if (stderr < 10 * .Machine$double.eps * max(abs(mx), abs(my))) stop("data are essentially constant") : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In mean.default(x) : argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
2: In mean.default(y) : argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA